# Styling an image map

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dictionary

Can `<map>` and `<area>` be styled ?
If not, what's the simplest (and most modern) way to style different zones of a single image ?

The nice thing about `<map>` and `<area>` is that with an image map generator you don't have to calculate the position of each zone. But it seems that even though there's an href attribute, you can't style areas.

I want the zones to have `{background-color: black; opacity: 0.5;}` and `:hover {opacity: 0;}`

I could make each zone a separate image but then I would have to reassemble them into one image and I'll never feel satisfied with this.

Perhaps I could use the speed optimized technique (sprites) where I put all graphics I need into one image and display only the one I need (games do this for textures and letters).

If anyone has a lighter javascript solution than http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/ I'm also interested.

Comment: Would it help if you created black zones ABOVE the image, and make them go from opacity 0.5 to 1 on hover instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the image a background image and place invisible `<a>`s over top with `display:block;position:absolute;` etc. and then when you mouse over them, you could make them semi-transparent colors or add borders or something... that would probably look nice, and be relatively simple :)

**edit:** [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aUrMh/2/)

Comment: When I tried this solution earlier I had trouble with block/inline display. But it seems easy enough considering how simple my image is. So thanks.

Comment: I got a little problem now, it was fine when I had the code alone but now that I put it into my entire template the anchors (while positioned correctly) are tiny squares. I tried `display: block;` but that doesn't do it. @Mark

Comment: @user2534: Did you set the width and height?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem, for some reason when the code was alone it worked without `px` after the values, but not once in my template.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with image maps, I'd advice you to look at [ImageMapster JQuery plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/), it can realy help with many image-map manipulation tasks.

It can setup opacity and background color for selected and hover zones, as you want, and ever join different zones in one area, making them working together.

I haven't tried Mapper you named, because of it's non-commerce licence, what doesn't satisfy my developer needs. But I have tried ImageMapster myself and like how it works - it's powerfull tool under MIT licence, forked from older plugin MapHighlite.

And about lightweight... I doubt it's very important issue because javascript code works in browser, and don't slow down your server. And in case of DOM/styles manipulations works realy fast.