# Image map with overlay images not working + JSFiddle

Tags: css, image, dictionary, overlay

i want to create a network, with an grey base structure and many overlay images to make it colorfull. Also i use a js to make the image map responsive, wich works, but if i want to make overlay picture, the image map doesn't work anymore.

Here is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RNj5V/

```
.page-title-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.imgA1 {
    z-index: 25;
}
.imgB1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.imgC1 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may use `pointer-events:none;` to reach image underneath . http://jsfiddle.net/RNj5V/1/

But this won't work with older browser

Comment: Thank's dude!!! But is there any way to make it compatible with older browsers ? Because it is an educational website and it has to work with older ones :S

Comment: do not use a map if you want it compatible with older browsers , but links layed hover the image, or javascript to change image source, or transparent image with a sprite image as background.

Comment: In some browsers you can style and even rezise image/map/area http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/AJHmt or http://dabblet.com/gist/5586117 or similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017879/styling-an-image-map